Is this a valid network topology?
My goal is to create a new, completely separate, network.
A diagram of my idea:
.
My question is a basic one: does this topology make sense? I'm not sure if I need to replace the switch with yet another router.
I would like both networks to be able to access the internet. I am keeping the home network using it's default IP range of 192.168.1.1/24 and the new router is going to use 10.0.0.1/24.
Thanks!

I don't get why you need two routers if you control all of these networks yourself. Any router (perhaps except cheapest junk) will happily route for both private networks alone and is able to set up any protections between them as needed.

A router joins networks. So you’d need modem->router to join the ISP network and your home/office network. You could have a second network inside, with a separate router, but I’m not sure I see the point.
If the goal is to separate the wifi from everything else, a vlan could do it.
It’s worth noting that the technical definition of a router is different from the layperson’s use. So when you say router, do you mean a specific network device, or the box that you get from the store that is a modem, switch, WAP, and router all combined?

I think you may be conflating the use of routers and switches. A more sensible layout would look something like this:

A router connects different networks. A switch connects systems on the same network. In this model, we assume your router has multiple interfaces. Many home routers have at least four interfaces, although these may be attached to a switch rather than being distinct network devices. In many cases, these switches are VLAN capable and you can achieve pretty much the same configuration with a little bit of extra work.
The WAN link on the router would have whatever address is assigned by your ISP. Each LAN interface would have an address on a different network, e.g.:

192.168.1.1/24 for your home network interface (and all machines on the "home" network would have addresses in the 192.168.1.0/24 address space, and use 192.168.1.1 as their default gateway).

192.168.2.1/24 for your project network interface (and all machines on the "projects" network would have addresses in the 192.168.2.0/24 address space and use 192.168.2.1 as their default gateway).


This does require that your router is capable of handling DHCP for multiple networks. This is trivial with a device running openwrt/ddwrt or something like the ubiquity edgerouter-x; I don't have experience with other modern routers so I can't comment on their available features.

even cheap home routers have at least four interfaces Wrong. At least practically / effectively speaking, you would be provided with only one LAN interface that is connected to a 5-port switch (hence four LAN ports). (Although slightly better one would support VLAN.)

I think home routers with VLAN-capable switches are fairly common (although they may only support a limited number of VLANs), which would allow us to achieve effectively the same configuration as having distinct, non-bridged interfaces. Maybe I'm just fortunate in my collection of older hardware. I've updated the verbage in the answer.

@larsks The hardware typically does; commonly home routers have a six port switch; four LAN ports, one WAN and one CPU port, with VLAN's used to segregate WAN. With for instance OpenWRT this is exposed. The stock firmware typically does not expose vlan's however.
